# Grouping feature in Data Table or Grid for Angular

Tags: angular, grid, angular-material, angular5

We are working on Angular 5 with the material framework application and looking for a ui plugin that can help us with the requirement of grouping, paging and sorting in a table. [For an sample we are looking to have something similar in angular 5 application](https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-grid/angular-grid-grouping-component.htm)

We have opened a query with the material framework and getting shot down. Still under discussion, but don't think it would be a quick solution. [Link here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10660#issuecomment-377970476)

Has anyone implemented grid grouping with paging and sort in angular 4 or 5 can provide some help here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52706931/350188. However, pagination and grouping kinda trip over each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good question. I checked the issue you raised on GitHub. I don't think the answer was satisfactory either.

I am reluctant to use a plugin because then you become dependant on the plugin developer.

However, we have used the Kendo Angular Grid and it is certainly full featured – https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/

Comment: As per my comment on GitHub, perhaps this points the way to what you want.

Comment: We are using prime ng plugin for now, but it seems to be very heavy. We have discovered some additional inbuild prime ng feature like downloading data in .csv filtering , etc.