# How to groupBy rows in Mat-Table

Tags: html, angular, material-design, angular7

I have `mat-Table` with `filters` and i want to group the table by one of the `columns`.

I want to make it a collapsible row that just shows how much you have of "that" kind and you can press it to see every single `row` inside that group.

I will share my HTML(that's a snippet not the whole HTML :

```
<mat-checkbox  class="CheckBoxClass" value="clientType" [(ngModel)]="isChecked  " disabled (change)="updateFilter('LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR', clientType)" >{{clientType}}</mat-checkbox>
<br><br>
<mat-checkbox  class="CheckBoxClass" value="contSize" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" disabled (change)="updateFilter('AORKH_MCOLH', contSize)" >{{contSize}}</mat-checkbox>
<br><br>
<mat-checkbox  class="CheckBoxClass" value="storageType" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" disabled (change)="updateFilter('TAOR_QTSR_EBRI', storageType)" >{{storageType}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>


  <!-- Container Table -->
  <div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  [hidden]="!show"  >
      <!-- Location  -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="AITOR">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location

        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AITOR}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
          <!-- Type  -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="SOG_MCOLH">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Container Type</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.SOG_MCOLH}}</mat-cell>
```

This is my component `NgOnInit` :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result) => {
     //Data
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
      //Paginator
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = ((data: Container, filter: string): boolean => {
        const filterValues = JSON.parse(filter);
        let conditions = true;
        for (let filterKey in filterValues) {
          if (filterKey === 'SOG_MCOLH' || filterKey === 'LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR' || filterKey === 'AORKH_MCOLH' || filterKey === 'TAOR_QTSR_EBRI') {
              conditions = conditions && data[filterKey].trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValues[filterKey]) !== -1;
          }
          else if (filterValues[filterKey].length) {
            conditions = conditions && filterValues[filterKey].includes(data[filterKey].trim().toLowerCase());
          }
        }
        return conditions;
      });
      }
      )}
```

Basically what I want to achieve is a row that collapse and shows how many rows it has and you can press on it to open the rows.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't come out of the box with angular Material. There are some solutions to do it yourself.
Here is another SO post that gives some directions: [Angular Material mat-table Row Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217179/angular-material-mat-table-row-grouping)

The second [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-collapsible-groupheader) link provided there gives a good example of a table using grouped row.

You can also have a look at other libraries that include row grouping by default, if that's something your project allows.

Comment: these two answers have problems. 1st one is not what i need it just divides them into groups. second one uses filterPredict and i already use it so i cant use it again as it creates a duplication problem.

Comment: You can just modify the `filterPredict` to keep your filtering condition and merge them with the one from the example provided. There shouldn't be duplication issues doing so.

Comment: I don't really know how to merge them i don't have much experience with doing stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiTemplateDataRows` in `mat-table` to implement Row Grouping and Collapsible/Expandable Rows.
Here is working Stackblitz example : [mat-table-with-row-grouping-and-expandable-rows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-with-row-grouping-and-expandable-rows)

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnrdq.jpg)