# Angular material combine same column values in table and show only single value for multiple rows

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a field called purchase_id which is the same for multiple records. Many records have the same purchase_id. Currently, I am showing the same purchase_id for multiple records, but now I want to combine the cells which have the same purchase_id and show purchase_id only once for the same records
Thanks in advance
 My code

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="serial_no" matSortDirection="desc" class="mat-elevation-z8" >


      <ng-container matColumnDef="serial_no">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Serial number </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.serial_no}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total  </td>

      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="purchase_id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Purchase_id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.purchase_id}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>  </td>

      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="product_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Product Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.product_name}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>  </td>

      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantity </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.quantity}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{totalquant}} </td>


      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="buyingprice">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Buyingprice </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.buyingprice}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{(totalPrice)}}  </td>

      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="vendor_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Vendor Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.vendor_name}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>  </td>

      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date}} </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>  </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Maybe this answer from another question solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52706931/11258735

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem in the open source project [Koia](https://github.com/centeractive/koia) using a [RowSpanComputer](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/row-span-computer.ts) class. Within [summary-table.component.html](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/summary-table.component.html), the computed row spans are then used to define the `rowspan` attribute of the `td` element.

```
[attr.rowspan]="rowSpans[iCol][iRow].span"
```

The [rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) attribute specifies the number of rows a cell should span. The [RowSpanComputer](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/row-span-computer.ts) class computes the `rowspan` for each cell out of the specified table data (array of rows). It basically loops over the rows and increments the `rowspan` for cells as long as their value remains unchanged. As soon as the value changes, the corresponding `rowspan` is reset to zero.

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-row-span?file=src%2Fapp%2Frow-span.component.html)

Comment: Can you please elaborate. A stackblitz?

Comment: I updated my answer and will possibly provide a `stackblitz` later on

Comment: I now also added a `stackblitz` to my answer